# BASH: write the output of a command to a file

Tags: bash, time-command

I run a program multible time using a bash script, and I want it's output to be written in a file. However, I couldn't make the operator ">filename.txt" work... Here is my script:

```
for i in {1..10000000..10000}
do
    time ./merge $i>nn
done
```

can somebody help me out?

Update:

**The answer is:**

```
{ time ./merge $i ; } 2>> time.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`time` is a bit funny. It's a Bash built-in so the first thing you need to do is limit it to the right command. You can do that by grouping it with braces or subshelling with parenthesis.

Then you need to note that it outputs to `STDERR`. This won't be redirected by default but we can fix this by redirecting `STDERR` into `STDOUT` and then redirecting that.

Finally (as choroba spotted before me) using `>` will overwrite by default. Doing it in a loop will result in just the last iteration showing in the file. You want `>>` which will append.

```
{ time ./merge $i ; } >> nn 2>&1
```

If you don't want any original `STDOUT`, and just want the time output, you could run this instead:

```
{ time ./merge $i >/dev/null 2>&1; } 2>> nn
```

This is junking all the output of the `./merge` command and is just redirecting the `STDERR` from the wider block.

---

Just as a test harness to show this working:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do { time echo $i >/dev/null 2>&1; } 2>> nn ; done
$ wc -l nn
40 nn
```

That's 10×4-line time blocks (the echo output is suppressed).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have replaced the command time ./merge $i>nn with the command you provided above, but still, I get time printed at my terminal...

Comment: Maybe the redirection needs to happen within the braces... Try the edit.

Comment: No, still it doesn't work...

Comment: I'm just an idiot. Position matters. The edited version should work. I tested it this time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oli. Unfortunately, it still does not work for me...

Comment: Is it possible that merge takes the "2>&1 ; } >> nn" as parameters as well?

Comment: No, they should all be eaten by the shell. You can check $@ from within the script though. I've been testing this with `ls` as my command and it's worked fine so far. What are you seeing?

Comment: This is the answer, and the command I use now  { time ./merge $i ; } 2>> time.txt

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the file in every iteration of the loop. Either, redirect the whole loop to the file

```
for i in {1..10000000..10000}
do
    time ./merge $i
done > nn
```

or, use append:

```
for i in {1..10000000..10000}
do
    time ./merge $i >> nn
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot choroba. However, the problem is not the append (I had also tried that before). I still get the outputs of the time command at my terminal...

Comment: This is better approach in my opinion. Instead of redirecting each iteration, this answer properly shows redirecting whole loop. +1 for that. As for `time` output,  it needs to be grouped either via curly brackets to run as list in current shell or parenthesis to run in subshell. And it writes to stderr, hence it must use &> redirection to include stderr stream into output file

Answer (score 1):

`time` prints its results to standar error, not standard output. You therefore need to redirect the former with `2>` instead of the latter with `>`. Your next issue is that you are capturing the output of `./merge` and not of `time`. So, you need to group the `time` and `./merge` commands and then redirect *their* output. This can be done either by running them in a separate subshell or by grouping them in the current shell:

1. Run in a separate subshell

   ```
   for i in {1..10000000..10000}
   do
     ( time ./merge $i ) 2>> nn
   done
   ```
2. Run in the same shell

   ```
   for i in {1..10000000..10000}
   do
     { time ./merge $i; } 2>> nn
   done
   ```

In this particular case, there is no practical difference between the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

The bash intrinsic time is not the same as /usr/bin/time.  The latter will allow you to append to a file:

```
/usr/bin/time --append --outout=outputfile command
```

Comment: OK, but bash's `time` looks different from what `/usr/bin/time` shows by default, so suggestion - use `-p` flag with `/usr/bin/time` to make it look the same